# Recursive printing accumulated value of numbers

Tags: c, recursion, accumulate

I have to print accumulated value of numbers using only recursion (loop or goto are not allowed), i wrote other similar functions which works fine but not this one.

For this `print_accumulated(0, 10, 40)`: 
a(0)-start of loop, b(10)-iteration value, c(40)-max value

it only prints 10 30, while program should print 0 10 30 60, and if i'm using another variable than a (sum for example) it prints 0 0 0 0.
Thanks for any help and advices.

```
void print_accumulated(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (a<c)
    {
        printf("%.0f ", a+=b);
        print_accumulated(a+b, b, c);
    }
}
```

Example how should it works but for different function (pow)
`print_square(0, 10, 40)` it prints 0 100 400 900

This one works fine

```
void print_square(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (a<c)
    {
        printf("%.0f ", pow(a, 2));
        print_square(a+b, b, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: When `print_accumulated(20.0, 10.0, 40.0)` is called, it prints `30` in the `printf("%.0f ", a+=b);`. It then passes `40.0` for `a` (`30.0+10.0`), running `print_accumulated(40.0, 10.0, 40.0)`. This stops the recursion as `40.0` is not smaller than `40.0`

Comment: Single-step through the program using your favourite debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It does not print 0 because you print `a+=b`, which, in addition to setting `a` to `a+b`, returns the result `(a+b)` - so your first time through, you print `(0+10)` which is 10.

It does not print 60, because 60 is greater than 40.  Why do you think it should print 60 given that you say that 40 is the max value?  And, just t be precise, if you do want the max_value to be printed, you should change the if test to `(a <= c)`, since `(a<c)` would mean it would not print it if it was equal to max_value.

Also, you seem to be incrementing twice in each loop.  Once in `a+=b`, and then when you recursively call `print_accumulated(a+b,...)` (as a has already been incremented by b at that point).  This is why it is skipping by 20 each time, instead of 10 (which, while you do not say is a problem, seems to be different than what the  iteration_value implies it should do).

Comment: But from what u said program wouldn't write 100 400 and 900 in second function because these numbers are greater than 40, also i don't want to print max value only 4: 0 10 30 60 (0, 0+10, (0+10)+20, (10+20)+30). I'm only want to accumulate printing value not whole 'a' variable, that's why i'm doing 2nd incrementation in ```print_accumulated(a+b, b, c);```

Comment: First, the second function (print_square) compares a to c, not a^2 to c.  So 10, 20 and 30 (the a value) are all less than 40.  It is a^2 (100, 400, 900) that you print, but a that you compare to c.

Comment: Second, it is not clear to me what the progression is that you're really looking for in print_accumulated.  But I would suggest that, when you code it, you not rely on side effects of things like a+=b.  If you use local variables to calculate what you want (in terms of things to print, and things to pass in to the next recursive call) and name them meaningful things, it will be easier to think about what is getting printed, and why.